# Is "ZFC + Omega rule for finite sets" a complete theory?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, alternative-set-theories

**Omega rule for finite sets $\omega^{fin}$:** if $\phi(y), \psi(y)$ are formulas in one free variable symbol $y$, then:

From:

for $ n=0,1,2,3,...; \text { we have: }
\forall y \ [y=\{x_1,...,x_n\} \wedge \phi(y)  \to \psi(y)]$

We Infer

$\forall y \ [ finite(y) \wedge \phi(y) \to \psi(y)]$

> Question: Is $ZFC + \omega^{fin}$ complete?

The idea is that if we take $\phi(y)$ to be "y is a finite von Neumann", then clearly this would be the Omega rule for standard naturals, and since ZFC interprets PA, then we'd have PA + Omega rule for standards. But would that be sufficient enough in itself to make the above theory complete?

Comment: Note in passing that since $P\land Q\to R$ is the same as $P\to(Q\to R)$, you don't need a separate $\phi$ in the formulation of your rule; you can subsume it into $\psi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm wildly misunderstanding your question, the answer is **no** - any $\omega$-model of ZFC automatically satisfies the $\omega^{fin}$-rule, but some $\omega$-models of ZFC satisfy CH and others don't.

More generally, we can develop forcing over arbitrary countable models of ZFC (and indeed, arbitrary *models*, if we use the Boolean-valued approach rather than the actual-generic-extension approach); since forcing doesn't add new natural numbers, any forcing extension of a model satisfying $\omega^{fin}$ will continue to satisfy $\omega^{fin}$.